# How to use Python regular expression to get Image src?

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

How to use regular expression to get src of image from the following html string using Python

`<td width="80" align="center" valign="top"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNFqz8ZCIf6NjgPPiTd2LIrByKYLWA&amp;url=http://www.news.com.au/business/spain-victory-faces-market-test/story-fn7mjon9-1226390697278"><img src="//nt3.ggpht.com/news/tbn/380jt5xHH6l_FM/6.jpg" alt="" border="1" width="80" height="80" /><br /><font size="-2">NEWS.com.au</font></a></font></td>`

I tried to use

```
matches = re.search('@src="([^"]+)"',text)
print(matches[0])
```

But got nothing

Comment: What is the '@' character supposed to match? There is no such character in your input string.

Comment: regular expressions and html?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/311220

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python regular expression for HTML parsing (BeautifulSoup)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/55391/), [Python Reg Ex. problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/90052/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just lose the @ in the regex and it will work

Answer (score 9):

Instead of regex, you could consider using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(junk)
>>> soup.findAll('img')
[<img src="//nt3.ggpht.com/news/tbn/380jt5xHH6l_FM/6.jpg" alt="" border="1" width="80" height="80" />]
>>> soup.findAll('img')[0]['src']
u'//nt3.ggpht.com/news/tbn/380jt5xHH6l_FM/6.jpg'
```

Comment: wouldn't Beautiful Soup add a lot of overhead to the solution? `img` tags are relatively easy to parse (and since they don't enclose other text, usually are formatted correctly)

Answer (score -1):

You could simplify your `re` a little:

```
match = re.search(r'src="(.*?)"', text)
```

Comment: It gets javascript files too.